# How to bulk delete all the users in an Auth0 tenant?

Tags: auth0, multi-tenant, reset, bulk, http-delete

I want to effectively "reset" one of my Auth0 tenant's used for testing purposes by deleting all the users.

According to the community forums it seems there is no way to do this.

Deleting them all one by one, whether by script or UI is unrealistic.

Deleting and recreating the tenant is an option but I would lose a lot of configuration settings which would also take me a good amount of time to re-configure and test.

Does anyone know of a solution other than this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Database Authentication and looking for a complete “reset” one-way of doing this is just to delete and recreate the database connection.

Not sure it would work for any other connection type though.

If you do this there is a short delay between when you delete the connection and when the users are removed in the UI, but it's a matter of seconds.